# .htaccess para URL amigável

Tags: php, apache, htaccess, url-amigável

Como que faço para criar regras `Mod_Rewrite (htaccess)` para minhas páginas? Não estou acostumado com `.htaccess`

Regras que gostaria:

`www.exemplo.com/index.php` para `www.exemplo.com`

`www.exemplo.com/perfil.php` para `www.exemplo.com/perfil`

`www.exemplo.com/perfil.php?p=fulano-da-silva` para `www.exemplo.com/perfil/fulano-da-silva`

`www.exemplo.com/video.php?p=fulano-da-silva&m=nome-do-video` para `www.exempli.com/perfil/fulano-da-silva/nome-do-video`

Código:

`.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?pag=$1
```

`url.php`

```
<?php
$atual = (isset($_GET['isw'])) ? $_GET['isw'] : 'home';
 $pasta = 'paginas';
if (substr_count($atual, '/') > 0) {
    $atual = explode('/', $atual);
    $pagina = (file_exists("{$pasta}/" . $atual[0] . '.php')) ? $atual[0] : 'erro';
    $id = $atual[1];
    $busca = @$atual[2];    

} else {    
    $pagina = (file_exists("{$pasta}/" . $atual . '.php')) ? $atual : 'erro';
    $id = 0;
    $frame=0;
}?>
```

`index.php`

```
<?php require_once('url.php') ?>
<?php include $pasta.'/'.$pagina.'.php'; ?>
```

Alguém poderia dar uma luz?

Comment: Injustiça tremenda aqui.. Editaram meu tópico tantas vezes que nem parece mais o que eu escrevi. O Tópico que vincularam ao meu não tem as mesmas características, o cara formulou a pergunta e só colocou o .htaccess, eu gostaria de saber como poderia selecionar qual o nível por PHP.. Esse fato de qualquer um poder editar o que você escreve, as vezes acaba prejudicando alguém que tem uma dúvida justa. Eu por exemplo não consegui fazer o que buscava com as dicas passadas no outro tópico, até consegui alguma coisa, mas nada como eu precisava. As edições descaracterizaram meu tópico.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem esse material que é muito bom: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/modrewrite-tips-tricks.html

Está em inglês mas você vai achar muita coisa.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Foi vaga e pouco usual, mas foi o único que minimamente tentou ajudar.